# How can I select the items inside a dropdown after successfully navigating and opening multiple dropdowns on a webpage using Selenium for webscraping?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, dropdown

Using selenium to webscrape, but having trouble selecting items after clicking a button that opens up a dropdown on webpage and does not go to a new url. After successfully navigating and openging multiple dropdowns on webpage, I cannot grab the items inside the dropdown.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(
    "https://www.usgbc.org/projects/?Country=%5B%22United+States%22%5D&Rating+System=%5B%22New+Construction%22%5D&Rating+Version=%5B%22v2009%22%5D&Certification=%5B%22Platinum%22%5D&State=%5B%22Texas%22%5D")
# check this is the right website
# print(driver.title)

# list of building names to quickly check what has been added
buildings = []

# lists for items on project page
cert_type_list = []
level_list = []
points_list = []
cert_date_list = []
sqft_list = []

# dataframe to collect all building information
df_main = pd.DataFrame()
# dataframe to collect building profile data on page
df_profile_data = pd.DataFrame()
# dataframe to collect scorecard data


# make this happen for next button

while True:
    
    try:
        
        project_profiles = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "grid-item--title")
    
        for i in range(len(project_profiles)):
            # Wait for page to load as order of elements will be incorrect otherwise
            time.sleep(1)
            
            project_profiles = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "grid-item--title")  # Find the list again
            
            # append and add to df
            building_name = project_profiles[i].text
                    
            buildings.append(building_name)
            print(building_name)
            
            # enable if checking all
            # building profile page information grab##############################
            # load building profile page
            building_profile_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//div[@id='result-grid']//h1[text()='{building_name}']")
            building_profile_link.click()
            time.sleep(2)
            
            # get values from tables on page
            row_data = []
            col_data = []
            
            # the row typicaly starts with td[]##
            # copy path of first row then make it end in /td, copy Xpath not entire path
            rows = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='certificates']/tbody/tr/td")))
            # the col typicaly starts with th[]##
            # copy path of first row then make it end in /th, copy Xpath not entire path
            columns = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='certificates']/thead/tr/th")))
            
            for row in rows:
                row_data.append(row.text)
                
            for cols in columns:
                col_data.append(cols.text)
            
            #time.sleep(5)
            
            print(row_data, "row")
            print(col_data, "col")
            
            df_profile_data = pd.DataFrame()
            df_profile_data.append(row_data)
            
            ################################SQFT##########################################
            
            import requests
            get_url = driver.current_url
            print("The current url is:"+str(get_url))
            
            URL = get_url
            html = requests.get(URL).content
            df_list = pd.read_html(html)
            df = df_list[-1]
            SQFT = df.iloc[0,1]
            SQFT = SQFT.replace('sq ft', '')
            #print(SQFT)
            
            # load credit score card page##########################################
            #building_scorecard_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//div[@id='project-details--wrapper']//h1[text()='Scorecard']")
            building_scorecard_link = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Scorecard')
            #/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]
            building_scorecard_link.click()
            time.sleep(2)
            
            # grab data on categories point totals
            point_data = []
            point_total = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'category-score')
            for points in point_total:
                point_data.append(points.text)
            print('cat scores', point_data)
            
            #expand credit areas
            sus_link = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'category-title')
            for i in sus_link:
                i.click()
                print(i.text)
                
                #if i == 'SUSTAINABLE SITES':
                    
            # grab specfic credit name
            credit_names = []
            credit_names_find = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'credit-name')
            for i in credit_names:
                credit_names.append(i.text)
            print('cred_name', credit_names)
            
            # grab data on category points
            sus_data = []
            sus_point_total = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'num')
            for points in sus_point_total:
                point_data.append(points.text)
            print('sus scores', sus_data)
```

I tried using the class_name and xpath but neither of them grab any information from the website. The lists for credit_names, and sus_data are the lists that I am appending items to after I open all the drop downs. I am just a little confused why I cannot find the elements. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!